# Symfony 2.3 / FOSUserBundle: Redirect

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FOSUserBundle and I require the ability to after login go same page which I used for login ?

This time when I login then redirect to home page and I want redirect to same page .

How it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change where the login form redirects after a successful login using the various config options. By default the form will redirect to the URL the user requested (i.e. the URL which triggered the login form being shown). For example, if the user requested http://www.example.com/admin/post/18/edit, then after they successfully log in, they will eventually be sent back to http://www.example.com/admin/post/18/edit. This is done by storing the requested URL in the session. If no URL is present in the session (perhaps the user went directly to the login page), then the user is redirected to the default page, which is / (i.e. the homepage) by default. You can change this behavior in several ways.

Comment: Any example in FOSUserBundle ?

Comment: This applies to Symfony in general, but it will work the same if you are using FOSUserBundle. you just need to override the afterloginsuccess handler